# Edit Programmatically plist in the App bundle at development time

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, plist

I have created a plist on XCode that will have a few values that I can't insert manually. So I want to add this values programmatically at development time. But it seems that I can only read the plist I can not save a plist that is on the App bundle, which makes sense at runtime.. When I will distribute my app I want everyone to have this plist file that's why I am not saving on documents or cache. How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.karelia.com/cocoa_legacy/Foundation_Categories/NSFileManager__Get_.m (pasted below) you can build a path within the user's personal library with the `-(NSString *) pathFromUserLibraryPath:(NSString *)inSubPath` method found there.

For example, `NSString *editedPlist = [self pathFromUserLibraryPath:@"my.plist"];` gets you the name of the modified plist within the user's library (even if that plist doesn't exist yet).

How you read/write it is according to what kind of plist you have, but you could read it into a dictionary with:

```
NSMutableDictionary *thePlist= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:editedPlist ];
```

If you are unable to read, easily detected by, for example `[thePlist count] == 0`, then you would instead call the same `initWithContentsOfFile:` initializer with a path to the template within your bundle, but you would then write the plist out to the `editedPlist` path so it appears in the user directory.

---

Here is the utility method I referenced above:

```
/*
    NSFileManager: Get the path within the user's Library directory
    Original Source: <http://cocoa.karelia.com/Foundation_Categories/NSFileManager__Get_.m>
    (See copyright notice at <http://cocoa.karelia.com>)
*/

/*" Return the path in the user library path of the given sub-path.  In other words, if given inSubPath is "foo", the path returned will be /Users/myUser/Library/foo
"*/
-  (NSString *) pathFromUserLibraryPath:(NSString *)inSubPath
{
    NSArray *domains = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString *baseDir= [domains objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *result = [baseDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:inSubPath];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't want every user to create this plist file. I want to create it once at development time and then distribute this file along with the app. By creating the file in the user's personal library that isn't possible I guess..

Comment: You're sending mixed messages :)  If you want to create it once, simply create it (however you like) as part of your development process, and include it within your app as a resource. You said the links in @gran33's weren't helpful because they create the plist elsewhere, but if you only need to create them at dev time that isn't relevant... create them wherever you like / however you like, include them in your project, and as a build step, copy them to the app bundle.

Comment: Of course.. I was being silly. I thought the file created wouldn't be easily accessible. I just created the plist file in my desktop folder and dragged to XCode and it's done! :)

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is writing code that checks for the plist in the documents directory at start. If it's there, read it into memory.

If you don't find the file in the documents directory, read it from the app bundle instead. Then drop into the code that uses it from memory and writes the changed version to the documents directory.

Remember that all the objects you read from a plist file are read as immutable, even if you wrote mutable objects into the file. You have to write code that makes mutable copies of anything that you want to change. (And have to implement a mutable deep copy if you have complex structures like arrays of dictionaries that in turn contain arrays of strings.)